# Arduino Uno will not connect to MAC computer running Sierra

Tags: arduino-uno, mac-os

I purchased an Arduino Uno. I am trying to set it up, but when I got to the "port" on my MAC, there is no option to select anything related to my board. The only connections the port tab allows me to connect to is the bluetooth incoming port, which is not correct because it gives me errors when I try to set up the UNO to block on and off for 1 second. I know this is the legit Arduino Uno, so why is the bluetooth not connecting?

Comment: Your board _is_ plugged into a the Mac via a USB cable, and the boards power LED is lit? There should be an entry in the Tools | Ports menu that doesn't appear when the board is not plugged in. And you have to close and reopen the menu each time you plug/unplug a board; the menu only updates each time you open it. Are you sure the USB cable is a full cable - data wires as well as power? Not all of them are. Then try another cable, another port, another Arduino, another Mac, until you've eliminated the faulty component.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have installed Arduino IDE on your mac and connecting board to mac using USB cable. Many time it happens due to driver or OS reason. Just plug the Arduino to another USB port and it should work.